# How to listen lambda function in Angular or React - Frontend?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, frontend

I am trying to create an app using `NodeJS` with `AWS Lambda` function, on the frontend side either `React or Angular` will be used.

If I use `Firebase` then on the frontend side(either React or Angular), I can listen to the keys using `on` method, also the `child_added`, `child_removed`, `child_changed` functions are there in firebase which automatically triggers whenever a value changed in the realtime firebase database.

I want a similar way using DynamoDb and Lambda functions in the backend, in the frontend, I can get a callback when the particular key is changed as I have heard AWS DynamoDb can handle large requests and much more scalable.

I didn't find any relevant articles too for the same how can I implement the same on the frontend side

Do let me know if still, you have any questions.

Comment: angular or react or vanilla javascript can listen only to event like  ajax calls response

Comment: Then how can I build web app using these things